# Checking condition safety and evaluating in same if statement

Tags: java, type-safety

Is it considered to be good practice or even safe to check if a condition can be evaluated and then evaluating the expression in the same if statement?

For example:

```
int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
int index = 4;
if (index < values.length && values[index] == 4) {
    System.out.println("value is 4")
}
```

In this example the condition is `values[index] == 4` and I am using `index < values.length` to check if it is safe to call it. However, I am doing this in the same if statement. Is it ok to do this?

Comment: && and || are there for this reason. If you use & or |, all the statements are evaluated. I don't see any drawbacks in your code.

Comment: As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033085/if-statement-with-where-the-first-condition-needs-to-be-true-before-testing-t), yes, it is safe. The second condition is tested only if the first one is verified

Comment: This example is too short to be meaningful and actually used in production.

Comment: @AdamSiemion It is a short example that demonstrates the problem, no? That doesn't mean that it has to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is correct approach, because in Java there is mechanism called *short-circuit evaluation* (called also *lazy evaluation*). That means JVM checks for first condition and if this is false JVM knows that no matter what result is in second condition it won't change anything, so second condition is skipped. In your example if `index` is greater than `values.length`, the whole if statement is false, so second condition is omitted.

---

Edit:

As [Coffee Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529061/coffee-ninja) mentioned, there is significant difference between bitwise operators (`&`,`|`) and logical operators (`&&`,`||`). Technically result should be the same, but bitwise operators are evaluated eager, so both sides are proceeded. This may result in `OutOfBoundException` in your example.
 What's more, bitwise operators have lower precedence, so if you accidentally mix logical and bitwise operators, you can receive [different results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13827666/7751059).

Comment: To make your answer even better and informative, I suggest you add a reference to the bitwise `&` operator, which works like `&&` on boolean values except it doesn't short-circuit.